# Skin and hair color of zombies in iZombie

Tags: izombie-2015

In the very beginning of Season 2, Liv finds out that there are several rich zombies in Seattle and they regularly tan their skin and dye their hair in order to blend in the normal crowd. It is also mentioned in season 2 episode 1 by Major that this process is quite expensive and so only the rich are able to afford it.

But in Season 4, it is shown that almost every zombie in Seattle looks like a normal person. Is there any explanation given about it?

I haven't read the comic book on which it is based, so I would gladly accept in-world and off-world answers.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen Season 4 yet, but it stands to reason that normal economic factors come into play here.

1. Where there is a demand, capitalism says supply will be found.  If there's a huge market for hair dye and false tanning, suppliers will arrive.  With more supply comes competition, which drives prices down.
2. Now that they are zombified, the demands on their finances (assuming they can retain their jobs) are reduced - zombie don't require food or much in the way of climate control.  The brains they require are provided by Fillmore-Graves.
3. Subsidies.  Given the inevitable backlash against zombies which Fillmore-Graves anticipates, they have a vested interest in making it hard to identify zombies easily.  Thus, they may provide appropriate cosmetic treatments to zombies at reduced (or even no) cost.

There's no way to tell which of the above is 'the' answer, but many possibilities exist.  It will almost certainly end up being shown to be a combination of the three points above.

Comment: Your first point doesn't make sense unless there's economy of scale. More suppliers will come in only if prices are being driven up. Once enough new suppliers enter to reduce prices to  previous levels, there won't be an incentive to come in. Prices will end up being slightly more than they began. Your second point is also questionable; food isn't a large expense.

Comment: @Acccumulation - Food is a significant expense.  In 2013, the average American family spent 10% of its budget on food.  And there was absolutely a pull for cheaper cosmetics.  The number of people wanting the service increased by at least an order of magnitude, and the demographics shifted from the social elite towards the average person.  There's no way that resulted in higher prices.

Comment: Higher demand means higher prices, not lower.

Comment: @Acccumulation - briefly.  ***Higher demand only leads to higher prices when supply is constrained***.  Neither hair dye nor spray tan is a product which requires extensive training to apply, and neither is a product that is naturally expensive to have shipped into the city.  When demand spikes, it might take the supply a brief period to adjust, but suddenly you'll see many, many new dying salons and spray tan booths.

Comment: "Higher demand only leads to higher prices when supply is constrained." That's a bit imprecise. There is not a hard limit on cosmetic products, but the supply curve does have nonzero slope. It might be very small, making the price increase very small, but it is there, and it certainly doesn't lead to price decrease.

Comment: @Acccumulation - increased supply leads to price decrease and, when non-constrained, increased demand leads to increased supply.

Comment: You are simply repeating arguments that I've already addressed. Increased demand leads to higher prices. Period. Increased demand does not *directly* lead to more supply, it leads to higher prices which leads to more supply. That supply partially counteracts the higher prices, but the idea that it leads to lower prices than before, absent some further factor such as economy of scale, is absurd. If you wish to further discuss your lack of understanding of economics and logic, you should take this to chat.

Comment: I don't quite agree with the first point. Remember that the area is quarantined. So finding supply within that area would be very difficult. And the second point, I guess it does not help the fact that the zombies look like normal humans now. But then, the thrid point may well be it as it sounds the most plausible scenario

Comment: Yeah 3 sounds like the most likely explanation. Various members of Fillmore-Graves even query why Liv chooses to go natural, they clearly aren't too comfortable with people running around looking like traditional zombies, so it makes perfect sense that they would offer this facility.